# Where do I find documentation for older versions of google-cloud-python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

We've got a pretty extensive BI system built on `python 2.7`/`google-cloud 0.20.0`. We periodically add products from the Google Cloud Platform, and need to access documentation for the version of the python module we're using. Here is the relevant `pip freeze` if it helps:

```
gapic-google-logging-v2==0.10.1
gapic-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
gax-google-logging-v2==0.8.1
gax-google-pubsub-v1==0.8.1
gcloud==0.18.1
google-api-python-client==1.5.1
google-cloud==0.20.0
google-cloud-bigquery==0.20.0
google-cloud-bigtable==0.20.0
google-cloud-core==0.20.0
google-cloud-datastore==0.20.1
google-cloud-dns==0.20.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==0.20.0
google-cloud-language==0.20.0
google-cloud-logging==0.20.0
google-cloud-monitoring==0.20.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.20.0
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.20.0
google-cloud-storage==0.20.0
google-cloud-translate==0.20.0
google-cloud-vision==0.20.0
google-gax==0.14.1
googleads==4.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.10.1
grpc-google-logging-v2==0.10.1
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.10.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here, although the url includes "latest", it's the 0.20.0 release:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/gcloud/latest/gcloud.pdf